# Datastructure for area and plots

Tags: c#, data-structures

I am developing a software wherein the scenario is as below. The customer has a big chunk of land from which he leases out small portions (say plots) to various customer. I would like to save in the database details of each plot. This is simple. The problem is I want to save the neighbouring plot also. This will help me in pulling out a report - Neighbouring plots with respect to a plot. Please advise a datastructure for the same.

Thanks & Regards
Sunil

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

`(Land_Id | Plot_Id FK)` - `PK` Add Land columns here

`(Plot_Id | Neighboring_PlotId FK to Plot_Id Allow Null)` - `PK` Add Plot columns here

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`.  The plot identifier is the key and the list contains the identifiers of its neighbors.  If each plot has a row,column location property then each neighbor will be (row - 1, column), (row + 1, column), (row, column - 1), (row, column + 1).  Of course you'll have to check if the plot is at the edge and adjust accordingly.